# Dynamic pages for DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am currently looking to create a site using DotNetNuke 6 for the first time ever!

My question is however, can I have 1 page with 1 HTML Module and then have multiple clients log in and supply me with different content? They must not be able to see each others content.

But I must be able to log in under HOST and see what client provided what content.

Also, are you guys happy with the workflow functionality in DotNetNuke? I am looking to purchase the Provisional Edition.

Comment: Are you wanting this content that they supply reflected in this HTML Module? Or is it OK for this user-specific uploaded-content to be displayed inside of a different module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to attack this problem - especially with features that are in the Professional Edition (i.e., workflow).  With workflow, you can not only put the content through a process of review (that you define), but you can also save, view, and rollback to a potentially unlimited number of versions of that content in history.  This allows you to also have insight into who and when that content was last updated.  In fact, the workflow feature can automatically email you when updates are pending.

Comment: So basically I need to get the Professional Edition?

Comment: If you want content workflow and support is important to you, then I would definitely suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the workflow question aside, the answer to your original post is to create some type of form submission.  If your clients have to log in and provide you with content that the others can't see, you'll need some type of module which accepts the inputs and stores the results based on their user id.   I don't know of such a module existing at the moment, but it wouldn't be very hard to build, depending on how fancy you want to get with the types of content they can post.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you utilize the Form and List module if you want to have users submit content that only they can see, and an admin/superuser can see the content each user submits.